# Critical Error after blue-screen / system crash - Thesis

Tags: errors, compiling

My PC crashed and somehow the **thesis.tex** file is **not compilable anymore**! Actually directly after the blue-screen it was it was blank. Because it was stored on a DropBox folder I changed the file with an older (20m or so) one. But Texmaker cannot compile it anymore.

I get critical errors, but the chapter and other files seem to be OK. Any clue?

Log-file chunk:

```
("C:\Users\...\Thesis.out"
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.1  
                                                                            ...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.1   
                                                                            ...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

[... 100+ times]                                          
                                                                            ...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.1 ...                                           
                                                                            ...
(That makes 100 errors; please try again.) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 8159 strings out of 493921
 121925 string characters out of 3144870
 216984 words of memory out of 3000000
 11389 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3938 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 841 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 38i,0n,38p,3787b,38s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting all of your auxiliary files (`.aux`, `.out`, `.toc`, _etc._) and rebuilding from a 'fresh' situation? The error here is indicated in a `.out` file, which will be reconstructed from your source `(.tex`) files.

Comment: @JosephWright Initially I tried. Didn't work. But :) it worked after taking the original template and copy-pasting the text into the `Thesis.tex` file. Thank you! Problem solved.

Comment: @JosephWright is it, maybe, possible to specify more precisely the files/file-endings in order to avoid deleting essential parts of the document by mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So. Joseph Wright had a good idea. Everytime something like this happens, you should first try to delete the auxiliary files `.aux,` `.out`, `.toc`, etc. (EXCEPT the `Bibliography.bib` or other files/folders made by you `.tex`-files).

If this dosen't work, you can try to take the original template and integrate the files and/or copy-paste the content inside. For me it worked. :) (make sure you read also the comment of the Question)